# How do I debug Magento search error?

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am using Magento v2.3.4. and I am getting the following error while search. The query from the error page as follows

```
 SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '43') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '43') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '66') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '66') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1') AND (())
```

How do I debug this? Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove last `AND (())` condition as follows:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '43') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '43') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '66') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '66') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1')
```

Comment: Hello, how to remove it? . I didn't add it.

Comment: From where you are getting this SQL statement? Please share sample code.

Comment: Hello, I am a beginner. Please let me know , if  you know how to debug this error

Comment: Yes, I'll help you. Please let me know on which page you are getting this error? or which action you are doing while this error appears to you?

Comment: The error occurs when I search for a product using a keyword like red, head, re or any numbers

Comment: Have you added any 3rd party extension or done any customization for search functionality?

Comment: No, I didn't do any customization for the search functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124469/discussion-between-dhara-bhatti-and-sandeep).